# Joins in the MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx, cross-join

Learning MDX now a days. I have a fact table. Schema + data is following

```
ColumnID1   ColumnID2   Amount
O1          null        100
O2          null        200
O3          null        300
C1          null        200
C2          null        400
O5          C2          300  
O4          C1          400
```

Query is to find the ColumnID2 not null values and add the amount of the row for that ColumnID2 Id  to amount in matching ColumnId1 row. e.g

Output

```
ColumnID1   ColumnID2   Amount
O1          null        100
O2          null        200
O3          null        300
C1          null        200
C2          null        400
O5          C2          300  + 400 
O4          C1          400  + 200
```

How this can be done in the MDX? Cross join is the thing coming to my mind but does not seem the right approach as it creates the cross product of the rows

Comment: First you should consider modelling it properly. A poorly designed model will always overshadow a beautifully written MDX.

Comment: @SouravA: This is not the actual modelling. Just the starting point. ColumnID1 is key (not surrogate). ColumnID2 is degerated dimension and Amount is measure. How i should approach to achieve the result

Comment: I agree with Sourav...instead of `ColumnID1` and `ColumnID2` why not just have `ColumnID` ? If you are unable to combine then please provide some Mdx examples so we can see what the dimensions, hierarchies and levels look like in the cube.

Comment: @whytheq: Thanks for comment. Cube has 1 fact and 2 dimensions tables. e.g Dim_Time with calendar hierarchy(year,quarter,month,date), Dim_Symbol  (Symbol_PK, other attributes).Dim_Symbol has no hierarchy. Fact_Amount (ColumnId1(PK),Date(FK),Symbol(FK),ColumnId2,Amount(measure)). ColumnId2 is degerated dimension which can not act as the primary key as it is common among many rows. Requirement is to have the above calculations for each date.